# cross domain cookie can only be reissued by origin server which created it?

Tags: asp.net, cookies, authentication, cross-domain

we are creating several web apps with asp.net mvc 5.2 and wif authentification. one of the web apps is the login-app, which authenticate all users for the other apps by creating a cross domain cookie. The Login itself is working great with the cross-domain cookie, the problem is when i want to reissue a cookie on the other web-apps (not the login app) to enable sliding expiration

I enabled sliding expiration on the other services (not the login service) like this:

```
        protected void SessionAuthenticationModule_SessionSecurityTokenReceived(object sender, SessionSecurityTokenReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
        DateTime validFrom = e.SessionToken.ValidFrom;
        DateTime validTo = e.SessionToken.ValidTo;

        var isNotExpired = now < validTo;
        var half = validFrom.AddMinutes(Constants.COOKIE_LIFETIME_MINUTES / 2);
        var isOverHalftime = now > half;

        if (isNotExpired && isOverHalftime)
        {
            SessionAuthenticationModule sam = sender as SessionAuthenticationModule;
            e.SessionToken = sam.CreateSessionSecurityToken(e.SessionToken.ClaimsPrincipal, e.SessionToken.Context,
            now, now.AddMinutes(Constants.COOKIE_LIFETIME_MINUTES), e.SessionToken.IsPersistent);
            e.ReissueCookie = true;
        }
    }
```

The cookie is not reissued after this code.

When i run this code on the login-service itself, the cookie is reissued.

What am i missing? Can cookies only be reissued by the server which created them? Unfortunatly i didnt find any informations on the web